# Why mock-function have not been called in test?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing tests for a component. It has a download-button. I want to test calling onClick function of this button. But it doesn't work. What's wrong with my test?

```
describe('download-button tests', () => {
  let wrapper:any;
  let _download = jest.fn(()=>{console.log('That`s Submit-button function')});

  jest.mock('../components/CustomButtonComponent', ()=>
    <button className="download" data-test ="download_button" type="submit" name="Скачать" onClick={_download}/>);

  beforeAll(() => {
    let wrapper = setupmount();
    const nextState = {
      ...initialState,
      selectedEntity: "1864296",
      disableTable: false,
    };
    wrapper.setState(nextState);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    console.log(findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'download_button').first().debug());
    findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'download_button').first().simulate('click');
  });

  test('download-button is clicked', () => {
    expect(_download).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

There is the result of `console.log(findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'download_button').first().debug());`:

https://sun9-10.userapi.com/c850124/v850124774/1ddcf0/_A7I6vHPHeM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because the onClick listener is attached to the child of `<CustomButton/>`, which is the `<button/>`. Have you tried passing the data-test prop down to the `<button/>` component? Otherwise try something like `findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'download_button').first().childAt(0).simulate('click')`.